# How to pass an error pointer in the Swift language?

Tags: swift

I am attempting to pass an error pointer in swift and am unable to do so. The compiler complains that "NSError is not convertible to 'NSErrorPointer'".

```
var error: NSError = NSError()
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: error)

if(error != nil)
{
    println("Error executing request for entity \(entity)")
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You just pass a reference like so:

```
var error: NSError?
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

if error != nil {
    println("Error executing request for entity \(entity)")
}
```

Two important points here:

1. `NSError?` is an optional (and initialized to `nil`)
2. you pass by reference using the `&` operator (e.g., `&error`)

See: [Using swift with cocoa and objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-XID_9)

Comment: When I do this, it seems I have to compare error to nil.

Comment: @ChrisPrince Ah, yes, that was changed in one of the later betas (I think beta 5, but I may remember incorrectly) - updated my answer, thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to pass just nil?

Comment: @kelin It's not impossible to design an API that would accept nil, but (1) ignoring errors isn't a great idea, and (2) Most APIs expect an NSError pointer, not nil - if the API docs don't explicitly allow nil, it could have some nasty side effects, even if it *does* compile

Comment: @Jiaaro, The question is about how to pass nil (or NULL) pointer to the function, what we able to do in Objective-C. `[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:NULL]` - here the example of passing NULL instead of BOOL pointer (to avoid discussions about necessity of error handling)

Comment: @kelin If the API allows it (like that one does) then yes, you can pass `nil`

Comment: As of Xcode 6, using `var error:NSError! = nil` gives a compiler error (wrong arguments), while the suggested `var error:NSError?` succeeds. I wonder why... (still new to Swift)

Answer (score 10):

This suggestion is up for discussion, but some engineers would prefer to use the golden path syntax:

```
var maybeError: NSError?
if let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &maybeError) {
    // Work with results
} else if let error = maybeError {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Comment: I definitely prefer this approach.