# Get Data from Api Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to call Api from `http://food2fork.com/about/api`, but I when I implement these code, it shows errors. I am doing like this tutorial here: [`https://www.topcoder.com/blog/calling-apis-parsing-json-with-swift/`](https://www.topcoder.com/blog/calling-apis-parsing-json-with-swift/)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ListDishsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var dishsTableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("hello")

    let logo = UIImage(named: "bento")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    dishsTableView.dataSource = self
    dishsTableView.delegate = self
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func loadDishesData() {
    let urlPath = "http://food2fork.com/api/search?key=67fd12776ee242546ac92d3122dabbd9&q=shredded%20chicken"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
      }

      var error: NSError?

      let jsonResult: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary
      if error != nil {
        // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
        print("JSON Error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
      }
    })
    task.resume()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DishCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListDishsTableViewCell
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }

}
```

But it shows errors like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: where have you declared 'err'? - I know it's a pain to learn things properly but you should read the Swift language book.

Comment: even though I declare it, it still error

Comment: add definition for variable err

Comment: check the update, I declared it, but it still error

Comment: @Woodstock please check again, I think the problem is here: &err. The & may not work well with swift2

Comment: declare it as var err: NSError?     
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084701/how-to-pass-an-error-pointer-in-the-swift-language

Comment: Yes, already let err : NSError?. But still not working

Comment: whats the error now? it must be different

Comment: It say: extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: @Woodstock Do you know the problem?

Comment: Ok, Eric, it now doesn't show any error, but why print(jsonResult) is not compiled?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31264556/2227743

Comment: I just want to follow this tutorial https://www.topcoder.com/blog/calling-apis-parsing-json-with-swift/ to get data from my API. Show please help me with this code like this tutorial. The next line is let json = JSONValue(jsonResult), but where JSONValue?

Comment: I've already given you the solutions, take example from these two links.

Comment: Sorry Eric, I forgot to call this function :)

Comment: No problem, Khuong. :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

In Swift 2, the `JSONObjectWithData` does not have the parameter `error`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:):

```
+ JSONObjectWithData:options:error:
Returns a Foundation object from given JSON data.

Declaration
SWIFT
class func JSONObjectWithData(_ data: NSData,
                      options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions) throws -> AnyObject
OBJECTIVE-C
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data
                 options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt
                   error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

Comment: Mr.Renzo please check it again, even though I declare it. It still error, please see my update question.

Comment: @khuong291, which swift are you using?

Comment: I am using swift 2, xcode 7

Comment: Then, [`JSONObjectWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:) has the parameter error only for Objective-C, and not for swift (where it can throws an exception).